# Comparing the exact and an approximation of the CDF function with R command ecdf

Tags: r, plot, probability, approximation

I want to compute the exact and an approximation of the Cumulative Distribution Function for the following density :

```
f(x)= U(x;-1,2)/2 + U(x;0,1)/2
```

where U(.;a,b) is the uniform density function on the interval [a,b].

I know how to compute the exact expression of the CDF.
My problem is that I do not understand why my approximation provided by the R function `ecdf` is a very bad approximation of the exact CDF (see code below).

```
#density function
f       = function(x){dunif(x,-1,2)/2+dunif(x)/2}
plot(f,-2,4)

#Approximation
xis     = runif(1000000,-1,2)/2+runif(1000000)/2
Ffapp   = ecdf(xis)
zs      = seq(-1.2, 2.2, by=0.01)
Ffs     = Ffapp(zs)
plot(zs,Ffs,type='l',col="red")

#exact expression  
Ffexact = function(t){(t <= -1) * 0 +
(t>-1 & t<=0) * (t+1)/6 +
(t>0 & t<=1) * ((t+1)/6 + t/2) +
(t>1 & t<=2) * ((t+1)/6 + 1/2) +
(t>2) * 1}
curve(Ffexact,-2,3,add=TRUE)
legend(-1, 0.9, legend=c("Fapp", "Fexact"),col=c("red", "black"), lty=1:1)
```

How to explain the bad approximation of the CDF obtained with the `ecdf` command ?

EDIT: here is the plot.
We can see that the approximation is quite far from the exact expression. But more importantly I say it's a bad approximation because we do not have convergence of the red curve to the black curve when the size of the sample (argument of `runif`) tends to plus infinity. Mathematically we should have pointwise convergence of the two CDF.

[image: plot]

Comment: Your simulation is for a different distribution, a sum of uniforms.  The density is for a mixture of uniforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you generate your random sample `xis`. If we look at its histogram, we can see that the distribution doesn't follow your density. `hist(xis)`:
[image: Histogram]

`xis` are just random values, you don't want to divide them by 2 (this shrinks the distribution) and instead of summing, you need to concatenate the two vectors:

```r
xis <- c(runif(1000000, -1, 2), runif(1000000))
```

Now the approximation fits perfectly:
[image: ECDF]